# compare a Value Cell with a certain number and define the interior color having regard of the comparison

Tags: vba, excel

I have the Value of a Cell1, want to know if this value is between certain number. When i know between which number is the Cell1, I change the interior color of another Cell = Cell2 respecting thie above condition. What i wrote look just for the first comparison although it`s false, and change the interior color of a false Cell. That's what I wrote:

```
Sub CellFormatColor()

Dim r As Double
Dim i As Integer

For i = 5 To 15
r = Cells(23, i)

If r > 5000 & r < 24999 Then
Cells(11, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 25000 & r < 49999 Then
Cells(12, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 50000 & r < 99999 Then
Cells(13, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 100000 & r < 249999 Then
Cells(14, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 250000 & r < 499999 Then
Cells(15, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 500000 & r < 999999 Then
Cells(16, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 1000000 & r < 1999999 Then
Cells(17, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 2000000 & r < 4999999 Then
Cells(18, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
ElseIf r > 5000000 Then
Cells(12, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

For example, r = Cells (23,5) = 200000. When it makes the comparison, the cells (11,5) changes of color although 200000 is not between 5000 and 24999. The true Cell have to be  Cell (14, 5).

Any help pleaase?

Comment: try using the word `AND` in the logic checks

Comment: @Nathan_Sav : that is a valid answer. You many want to post that?

Comment: Will do, cheers :)

Comment: Note that none of the tests in your code will evaluate to `True` if you have a value of, for instance, 25000. (25000 is not < 24999, nor is it > 25000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the word `AND` not `&` in your logic, would it not be possible to do something based around this

```
cells(10,i).offset(cint(r/24998),0).interior.color....
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can replace your `ElseIf` with `Select Case` :

```
Select Case r
    Case 5001 To 24998
        Cells(11, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case 25001 To 49998
        Cells(12, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case 500001 To 99998
        Cells(13, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case 100001 To 249998
        Cells(14, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case 250001 To 499998
        Cells(15, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case 500001 To 999999
        Cells(16, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case 1000001 To 1999998
        Cells(17, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case 2000001 To 4999998
        Cells(18, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

    Case Is > 5000000
        Cells(12, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)

End Select
```

Comment: ++ Good suggestion. BTW it can be written in 1 line ;) `Case 5001 To 24998: Cells(11, i).Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 100)`

Comment: I think this can all be done without the logic as an offset of the integer of dividing by 24998, so `cells(10,i).offset(cint(r/24998),0).interior.color....`